# C++: instantiatiate array of objects that contain pointer to char array

Tags: c++, char, heap-memory

```
class A
{
    char *name;
public:
    A();
    A(char*);
    ~A();
};

A::A()
{

}
A::A(char* s)
{
    int k=strlen(s);
    name=new char[k+1];
    strcpy_s(name,k+1,s);
}
A::~A()
{
    if(name!=NULL)
        delete[] name;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A *v=new A[20];
    delete[] v;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error at runtime: **Unhandled exception at 0x5B987508 (msvcr110d.dll) in test212.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDC1.**
It's obviously a memory problem, but can you please tell me what happens in this example of code?

Comment: If you're writing C++, don't write C. Choose between C and `char *` or C++ and `vector<string>`.

Comment: Where are you initializing name to null?;)

Comment: make name = nullptr in the "default" constructor.

Comment: Initialize `name` to `NULL` in your default constructor.

Comment: This is pointless code. Just say `std::string name;` in your class definition and leave the dynamic memory management to people who have had more time to spend on this than you. You have more important things to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new A[20]` calls the default constructor, and you don't initialize `name` in the default constructor. You can't assume that it will be set to `NULL` for you. In the absence of initialization, `delete[] name` has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

`A *v=new A[20];` constructs new `A` objects via the default constructor `A::A()`. Your custom constructor `A::A(char* s)` never gets called and therefore, `name` is never allocated any memory. When the destructor is called, you are trying to `delete[]` memory that just isn't there. That results in the exception you see.